# Making TimePicker not changeable

Tags: java, android, timepicker

In Android java, how can I make a TimePicker unchangeable? Just like Editable or Enabled with an EditText.
I'm making an application, where it's showing a pre-set time, and then I don't want the user to be able to change it, until they tick a checkbox.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If setEnabled(false) does not work, 
try to extend DatePicker widget, override onTouch and remove focus from DatePicker(or DatePicker childs)

Comment: Yeah, enabled works fine, it's just that it's really grayed out when not enabled, which makes it hard to see. :) It's also what I will end up with, if I don't find a better solution. :)
Wouldn't removing focus still make it tick up/down if hitting the arrows, or make the keyboard appear and re-appear if touching the textfield?

Comment: You can actually go to all childs and override styles for them(for example where childView instaceOf Button). First my advice look more accurate.